# SPOJ solution submission

Tags: java, solution

I am a newbie trying to submit a solution for problem on SPOJ in Java. I have written a code in Java with class name Graph and file name Graph.java. But on submission, I am getting compilation error as:

```
Main.java:18: error: class Graph is public, should be declared in a file named Graph.java
public class Graph {

       ^
1 error
```

Can someone point out what is wrong with my file name?

Comment: Just do what is suggested. Let the name of your class and the name of your file be the same. [More](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SPOJ Java solutions must be submitted with a `Main.java` file that contains the `main` method. See the "[Solution to TEST in Java](http://discuss.spoj.com/t/solution-to-test-in-java/59)" for an example, which states:

> The main class of the program must be called Main.